# update related records

Tags: apex

I have one custom object called Student__c and look up relation for contact

now my scenario is I have field called Results pick list filed in student__c.
if(Results__c == 'FAILED') my Contact sttaus should be  deactive.

```java
public static void resultsforstudent(list<Student__c> newlist, Map<Id,Student__c> oldMap){
    list<contact> conlist = new list<contact>();
    set<Id> acids = new set<Id>();
    for(Student__c students :newlist){
        if(students.Result__c == 'FAILED' && oldMap.get(students.Id).Result__c == 'PASS' ){
            acids.add(students.Id) ;  
        }

        if(!acids.isEmpty()){
            for(Student__c students :[select id, Name, Results__c])
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, this isn't really a question. You have a statement, and some code (which has syntax errors), but you haven't told us what you're stuck on. Please [edit] your question to make your code valid, and to tell us what, specifically, you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it something like this, I have written a general code, you have to change your api names so match your requirements

Hope it helps!

```
public static void changeCStatus(List<Student__c> Students){ 
    Set<Contact> cSet = new Set<Contact>(); //set to prevent duplication of contactId, I am assuming one multiple student can have same contact.
    for (Student__c s:Students){
        if (s.Results__c == 'FAILED'){
            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.Id = s.Contact__c;
            c.Status = 'Deactivated'; //change c.(status field in contact api name)
            cSet.add(c);
        }
     }
    List<Contact> cList = new List<Contact>(cSet);
    upsert cList;
}
```

I have edited the code above, special thanks to this website [here](https://www.levelupsalesforce.com/how-to-convert-a-set-to-list-in-apex). Where it teaches how to convert a set to a list in Apex.

Comment: typically this could be done in a record triggered flow as well... no real need to go through apex trigger. but indeed the above code would do the trick

Comment: Hi, code almost working fine  error throwing  DML require Sobject or sobject list  while  upsert clist

Comment: Glad it helped, I have edited the code for you, I am sorry you cannot upsert a set, you have to change it to a list before upserting. Please check the edited code above :)